# Is it possible in aws to have the same IP for EC2 and for a Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, udp, amazon-vpc

The problem is we are working with **UDP** based IoT devices, what we want to achieve is that there's a **server** which receives the incoming **udp packets** and we will have a **lambda** connected to an **sqs** which sends different packets what comes from the **sqs**. **In order to be able to send packets back to the device, it has to come from the same source, meaning the same IP and PORT**.

I'm looking for possible solutions, the main idea is to separate packet processing from packet sending into different services.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyNbc.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

I think, here is a solution:

1. Create [NAT Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) that allows IoT Devices to communicate with EC2 instances (need to setup iptables which allows IoT devices IP's to get access to the EC2 instances)
2. Em-place Lambda functions and EC2 instances in private subnets and allow internet access though NAT Instance

It works only for IP address, each time Lambda will send data to IoT device though NAT instance, packet source port will be ephemeral.